# Using gContains to test whether lat lon points lie within a map

Tags: r, google-maps, gis

I have a map of an area obtained from the gmap function in the dismo package. I am then trying to test whether certain latitude and longitude points are within that map.

Here is my reproducible example:

```
library(dismo)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(XML)
library(rgeos)


spatP <- SpatialPoints(gmap("Palo Alto, CA", lonlat = TRUE), 
    proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat"))

point <- data.frame( x =  -122.129610, y = 37.399761)
pointSp <- SpatialPoints(point, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat"))

gContains(spatP, pointSp, byid = FALSE)
```

That point is within that map, but I am obviously missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution. If I turn the SpatialPoints data frame `spatP` into a convex polygon, it works.

```
polyHull <- gConvexHull(spatP)
gContains(polyHull, pointSp)
[1] TRUE
```